# Best way to determine the direction my UIPageViewController was swiped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swipe, uipageviewcontroller

I have set up a UIPageViewController that has **five** view controllers the user can swipe between in a **loop**.

I use these **two methods** two either increase or decrease an **int variable** called swipeTotal that I use to determine the **index of an array** so I can display for example **200 different strings from an array in order using five view controllers that loop.**

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
         viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    swipeTotal = swipeTotal - 1;
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
          viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {

    swipeTotal = swipeTotal + 1;
}
```

This seems to work to determine if the user swiped forwards or backwards, however these two methods seem to be called **twice every time the swipe direction changes** causing the swipeTotal to be **out of sync** for 1 swipe everytime the user changes direction.

I can't use this method because I want the swipeTotal int variable to increase if the user swiped forward and decrease if the swiped backward **everytime and not be canceled out by the methods both occasionally being called.**

So what is the best way to determine what direction the user has swiped so I can increase or decrease an int variable accordingly? I have tried to find a way but have had no luck, there must be a simple enough way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a `UIScrollView`? If you are, then you can access the `contentOffset` property to determine the direction

Comment: Nope I am using the default UIPageViewController and thats it, can it be done with the UIPageViewController?

Comment: The `UIPageViewController`'s `view` does contain a `UIScrollView`.  You could, for example, KVO the `contentOffset` property.

Answer (score 1):

Use `willTransitionTo` to determine nextIndex and then assign real value at 
`didFinishAnimating`

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]){

                guard let viewController = pendingViewControllers.first else { return }
                guard let index = viewControllers.index(of: viewController) else { return }

                nextPage = index
            }
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

                if completed {

                   currentPage = nextPage

                }


            }
```

Comment: Way to go... Superb